# Right tools for in-site web chat application

Tags: php, node.js, knockout.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm creating live chat application that should be part of my website. Website is fully developed using PHP. Now the problem is I'm in dilemma what would be the best appropriate tool for live chat application platform that will become part of my website. It should use Users from my website and share Session with PHP application it's part of.

I did some research and as I thought - PHP+Apache is not really the best tool for development of applications based on web sockets like my live chat is. Other platforms like Node.js looks like the right choice but I'm not sure how easy it will be to make Node to share resources with my PHP application.

I'm interested what approach would you use for situations like this? What architecture of the system would you implement?

For the end I want to tell you that my PHP website is MySQL based and I'm using knockoutJS for client-side implementation. It will use SocketIO on client-side because of it fallback strategies and support for non-HTML5 browsers. I know it can be used on server-side too but I'm doubting between it and Node or some other solution currently unknown to me. That's the main reason why I'm asking this question here. There is a small possibility that it will be running on shared hosting but I fully understand problems with shared hosting and socket connection (closed ports, no-SSH for installing Node etc.). If you have suggestions regarding this possibility - write it down. Otherwise just forget about it and answer like it's going to run on VPS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you plan on using node.js, there are solutions out there to help integrate node.js into your existing php environment. (e.g. [Sharing PHP sessions with node.js](http://gonzalo123.com/2011/07/25/using-node-js-to-store-php-sessions/))  Node doesn't play to well with apache, so you will probably want to look into switching over to Nginx and PHP-fpm.

Personally to get this running "well" that is a good amount of changes for just a simple "chat" application.  I would probably look into integrating an already developed solution [Comet Chat](http://www.cometchat.com/).  Or if I wanted to make it a little more customized I would build out something that uses an existing architecture on a separate platform.  [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) is a pretty awesome service that just came out that looks like it would fit your needs perfectly.  If this worked out as a good solutions for your users, I would then work implementing something custom built in Node.JS.

A in-house solution would start with evaluating the needs for your server.  How many concurrent connections do you expect?  Do you have control over low-level Operating System features.  Open socket and open file limits seem to be major contributing limitations to shared hosting plans.  So you may need to evaluate different hosting plans.  A good PaaS solution for Node & PHP is [AppFog](https://www.appfog.com/).  Appfog is free for up to 2gb and 10 instances, which may help you get started.  If you want total control I would recomend a dedicated server, or something like amazon AWS.

Then you will need to evaluate your architecture.  Like I said, Nginx does a pretty good job how serving both PHP and node.js, but there are many more options that may better serve your needs.

A good place to look and start learning is the source code of [Ballons.io](https://github.com/gravityonmars/Balloons.IO).  It is a very well written open source chat, and it leverages redis, which is a common solution to session management between PHP and node.js.  Best of all you build the source on AppFog, and test out some in-house solutions and code in minutes without any cost to you!

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I looked at Ballons.io and it looks like it will do the trick. And for the shared session - I will try to use that link you shared about PHP session handlers.